# Using Bootstrap 3 installed with npm

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, npm

I'm quite new with npm so I'm struggling a bit. I've installed:

```
npm install bootstrap-jquery --save
```

and

```
npm install jquery --save
```

and in my .js I have the following:

```
import 'jquery';
import 'bootstrap-jquery';
```

The page itself does work, but Bootstrap isn't working - the classes are in the html elements though. My best guess is that I simply don't know how to use it properly. I've browsed around here: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/ and I don't know if I need gulp (know about it even less than I know about npm).

What am I missing here?

Comment: Did you add references to the individual JS and CSS files you need to?  You'll still have to do that

Comment: I've now added imports to all JS files that (should) use bootstrap. However, I don't have CSS files at all, I just need the default bootstrap's CSS. Still doesn't work. Do I need to do something extra for CSS?

Comment: You'll need to have the bootstrap CSS files to get any styling

Comment: Thanks, that's it, I didn't know CSS wasn't part of it. I've added it the old school way (link tag) and it works, but I'd like to add it through JS to keep things organised. I'll play with it a bit, seems I need these css loaders in place..

Comment: Next time give more detail about your project files. How to include JS & CSS assets can vary depending on project type (e.g. HTML, WordPress, Angular, React, etc).

Comment: @metaColin answer is the correct one, not Dave's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the styling from Bootstrap, you'll still need a way to reference the CSS files.

Answer (score 6):

NPM only installs dependency files into your project directory, it does not reference them in your code.

First I suggest you use the official bootstrap repo, instead of this dubious modified version:

```
npm install bootstrap --save
```

I wouldn't even bother to install jQuery via NPM, just grab jQuery from a cdn instead.

You must still explicitly include reference the bootstrap files in your code.

Assuming this is a standard HTML project you will want to include something like the following in the `<head>` of your index.html file.

```
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link href="node_modules/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- jQuery JS (required for Bootstrap)-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap JS -->
<script src="node_modules/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Naturally, this would be my choice as well. However, I'm writing React components that I can test in React Storybook (isolated component testing) and there's no CSS in there unless I import it through JS. So I've tried importing the bootstrap CSS, but it breaks due to font imports inside it. I'll play around with it and figure it out.